# Correct way to load CSS in a codeigniter view

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

My base url in config is : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';`

My CSS folder is on root level(so **ci**).

In the view I tried:

```
<head>
    <style> @import url('<?=base_url()?>/css/styles.css'); </style>
</head>
```

and

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/styles.css">
</head>
```

both fail. what is the correct way to import a CSS file using the Codeigniter framework

Here is how my .htaccess file looks like :

```
    <IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Comment: check browser developer tools for 404.

Comment: Have you ensured that you can access it from the browser? `http://localhost/ci/css/styles.css`

Comment: @KeithChason yes!

Comment: I would next do what @Scriptonomy said, and how do you know it's "not working?"

Comment: it is just loading an empty page instead of a page with navbar. When I remove the link tag it's working, but without the css, ofc

Comment: have you loaded url helper? `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: No, but I just did, and it still won't work.

Comment: I think it's a CSS problem instead of CodeIgniter

Comment: Have you set the base url in the config.php Also make sure you have the assets out side of the application folder `$config['base_url'] = 'http:/localhost/project/'` make sure permission 0777

Comment: So what is generated link? Simple trick... View the HTML Source in your browser - eyeball the actual generated HTML and even copy that and paste it into a browser... do you see the css file?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw actually I can't see it in the html..

Comment: Can you see anything from the view you are sending to the browser?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, no, as I said, the page in the browser is empty/just white

Comment: If you HTML is not showing, there is something else going on here.So can you add in the controller/method you are using to display the view.

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach:

folder structure:

example.com
|_  application
|_  assets
|_  system

**CI 2.x**

I've set `$config['base_url']   = '';`, this will work for **local server** and **production server**

**CI 3.x**

WARNING: You MUST set this (`$config['base_url']`) value! so I use below code to differentiate between **local server** and **production server** :

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]=='ex.ample')
    $config['base_url'] =  'http://ex.ample/';
else
    $config['base_url'] =  'http://example.com/';
```

( I'm using at the local server a virtual host called `ex.ample`, change this to your needs)

in my folder assets I store `assets/css/style.css`

and call it in my view with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: You need to set the base url in codeigniter 3 > versions as it says in the comment above it.

Comment: @wolfgang1983: the leading slash makes it absolutely sure you loading a relative path, if you take it away CI 2.x might break...

Comment: I use it like `href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>"` because your base url all ready has `/`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes that's another correct approach, but you need to type more :)

Comment: When tried the above i got : Call to undefined function base_url()

Comment: @RobertRoss: you still need to load the helper `$this->load->helper('url')` in order to use base_url(). You can autoload this helper function, if your problem persist, I'd suggest to start with a new CI installation and adapt to the post here....

Comment: @RobertRoss auto load the url helper `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` or load helper on controller in the construct area

Comment: I tried both of the above @Vickel and still getting the fatal error.

Comment: I'd recommend to restart from scratch with a new CI installation, BTW your `.htaccess` file might need something like this: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|photos|videos|jssor|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)`, maybe you could show your htaccess in your question?

Comment: @Vickel I have two .htaccess files one in Views and one in System. Just pasted their content in my question.

Comment: and, btw I reinstalled the project and I am still having the same problem :(

Comment: I'm using  RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|photos|videos|jssor|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] this removes index.php and allows folders like assets, etc be accessable. This is .htaccess in the root. btw root, do a setup like in my answer, skipping the extra folder **ci**

Comment: But if i don't have the ci folder, then the codeigniter files will mix with the other files in the htdocs folder, so what do you mean skip it?

Comment: ok I see:, if you have on your local server a directory C:\ci\mysite.com\public.html, then this is your root. Set a virtual host pointing to that directory. On a production (shared) server you would find the root right under mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/styles.css">
```

you are missing a semicolon at the end of `base_url`

This code is ok ensure that you are giving correct path

you can also use

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/styles.css');?>">
```

Comment: **"you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block"**. see php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php